# SelectItem doesn't work but Inventory does

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I just found out how item tags work and now I'm trying to check if the player is holding the sword with the tag. When I try to `/execute if entity @e[nbt={SelectedItem:[{tag:{awakened:1b}}]}]` the test fails

but when i Try this command it works. `/execute if entity @e[nbt={Inventory:[{tag:{awakened:1b}}]}]` it works. I am holding the item and it still doesn't want to work

If you are wondering this is the give command I used to get the tagged sword.

```
/give @p minecraft:diamond_sword{Unbreakable:1,HideFlags:1,Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:sharpness",lvl:8}],awakened:1b,display:{Name:'[{"text":"Awakened arkhalis"}]'}} 1
```

Answer (score 3):

`SelectedItem` is not a list and therefore does not take square brackets. Try `/execute if entity @e[nbt={SelectedItem:{tag:{awakened:1b}}}]` instead.